# Properly populating tables in an Object Relational database

Tags: sql, oracle10g, object-relational-model

I've got a homework assignment that requires that I use Oracle 10g Express to implement an Object Relational database to track phone billing data.  I have a superclass of Communications with subclasses of Call, Text, and Data.  I'm hitting a snag with properly populating these tables so that I can find the appropriate data in the various tables.

My Types and Tables are declared as such:

```
create type CommunicationType as object (
  -- column names here
) not final;
create type CallType under CommunicationType (
  -- column names here
);
create type TextType under CommunicationType (
  -- column names here
);
create type DataType under CommunicationType (
  -- column names here
);
create table Communications of CommunicationType (
  -- Primary and Foreign key constraints here
);
create table Calls of CallType;
create table Texts of TextType;
create table Datas of DataType;
```

When I try to `insert` data into one of the subclasses, its entry doesn't appear in the superclass.  Likewise if I `insert` into the superclass, it doesn't show up in the appropriate subclass.  For example, `insert into Calls values (CallType( -- Values -- ));` doesn't show any data in Communications.  Nor does `insert into Communications values (CallType( -- Values -- ));` show anything in Calls.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's wrong?  You're thinking OOP in a SET based world

Comment: @OMG Ponies: I believe you. :)  So, am I misunderstanding that I should be able to access the information from within both tables or am I horribly misunderstanding *how* to set up the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created four separate tables. If you insert a row into one table, there is no reason to expect to see your row in another table.

Your tables based on `CallType`, `TextType` and `DataType` inherit their structure and behaviour from `CommunicationType`, but this doesn't mean that the data is replicated. I suspect you probably don't need the table `Communications` at all.

*< aside >* Personally, if I'm using the Oracle database I'd forego using object types entirely and just model the thing using a pure Relational model, but that's probably just me - and doesn't help you much since your teacher seems to expect you to implement an "Object Relational" database... :)

Comment: If skipping the `Communications` table is the way to go, I can handle that.  So, it would take 3 queries to get information about all Communications (one per table)?

Comment: You don't need 3 queries - a single query can pull data from multiple tables, in this case using a UNION.

Comment: Ok.  I'll go with that.  Thanks!